# Button onclick event (hard coded)

Tags: javascript, events, button, onclick

is it possible to check the e.button "directly" in the onclick tag?

**For example**

```
<div onclick="if(e.button == 1) { alert(e.button); }"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you put into `onclick` will be wrapped in a function so theoretically you can put any JavaScript there:

```
<div onclick="var e = event || window.event; if(e.button == 1) { alert(e.button); }"></div>
```

But it is not considered to be good practice as it is hard to maintain and mixes HTML and JavaScript. Better is to attach the function with JavaScript:

```
// given your HTML is
<div id="myDIV"></div>

// you can do:
document.getElementById('myDIV').onclick = function(event) {
   var e = event || window.event; 
   if(e.button == 1) { 
       alert(e.button); 
   }
}
```

---

[quirksmode.org provides every good information about JavaScript and events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It looks like :

```
<div onclick="javascript:var e = window.event; if(e.button == 1) { alert(e.button); }"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Btw. Did this work in every "new" Browser?

Comment: (a) The `javascript` label is unnecessary and confusing. (b) This will not work in Firefox (and I'm surprised it does in Chrome).

Comment: @Heandel: If you don't explain what the `javascript` label is doing, you will confuse novices who don't understand what it is and think that it is necessary to have it. In W3C compatible browsers the event object is passed as parameter to the event handler and is not available via `window.event` (this is a IE thing).

Comment: Right, it would not work in ff. The solution from FelixKling works.